# Passing node attributes into chef-apply

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Is there any way to pass attributes into a chef-apply run of a cookbook?

The very first line of my cookbook is:

```
if node[:my_attr][:enabled]
```

which leads to:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

when I run

```
chef-apply recipes/default.rb
```

Adding the appropriate attributes into the `attributes/default.rb` does not fix this problem, neither does adding an initialization for `node[:my_attr] = {}`.

How can I pass node attributes into a chef-apply run?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the attributes/default.rb 
declare

```
default['my_attr']['enabled']= "value"
```

then you would be able to access them in your recipe

You can also pass the value of your the attribute using the chef-client -j option.

Comment: I have that defined in my attributes/default.rb I have not attempted the -j option. Does it work with chef-apply?

Comment: -j option cannot be used with chef-apply ( that was my mistake ).
What is the problem that you are facing? your attributes are not reflected in the recipe?

Comment: none of the attributes defined in my attributes/default.rb are propagating into my cookbook when run through chef-apply. Defining them manually at the top of the recipe does work, but I would like to avoid doing that if possible so that the recipe can be run through chef-apply and regular chef.

Answer (score 0):

Abraham P has it right. `chef-apply` is much like a shell script interpreter. You can even hash bang your file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env chef-apply

# define attributes here

# create chef resources and other valid chef/ruby code
```